# apache poi - how to write and continue to loop row in the same cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have some problem with my looping. What I am trying to do is that I want to write the the date for whole month of december and then follow by the total date of the 2019 year. But the problem that I am having right now is the total date of the 2019 is not show up under the row of the same column as total day of December 2018

my current output(the row number of the 31 december 2018 falls on 34th row:

```
MONTH
------
2018-12-01
2018-12-02
2018-12-03
2018-12-04
...
2018-12-31
```

I think my problem is at the getRow and looping. Please help me.

```
// month

    int maxDay = cal1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    for (int dec = 1; dec <= maxDay; dec++) {

        Row row3 = sheet.getRow(dec + 2);

        Cell cell1 = row3 .createCell(2);

        cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dec);

        java.util.Date date1 = cal1.getTime();

        cell1.setCellValue(formatter.format(date1));
    }

    // for total date of a year 2018

    for (int notdec = 1; notdec <= 365; notdec++) {

        Row row3 = sheet.getRow(maxDay+3);  

        Cell cell1 = row3.getCell(2);

        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, notdec);

        java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();

        cell1.setCellValue(formatter.format(date));

    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but `Row row3 = sheet.getRow(maxDay+3); ` is always getting the same rows as `maxDay` is not incrementing.  Why are you not using the same code as for 12/2018?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am trying to continue to write the total date of the year 2019 after the last row of december 2018. I believe it relate to the getRow().

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried before but it wont work mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code that **is** working for `2018`

```
for (int dec = 1; dec <= maxDay; dec++) {
    Row row3 = sheet.getRow(dec + 2);
    Cell cell1 = row3 .createCell(2);
    cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dec);
    java.util.Date date1 = cal1.getTime();

    cell1.setCellValue(formatter.format(date1));
}
```

so to continue under this, for a start it would be logical to use the same code and just change what needs to be changed

```
for (int notdec = 1; notdec <= 365; notdec++) {

    Row row3 = sheet.getRow(maxDay +3 + notdec);  // THIS

    Cell cell1 = row3.createCell(2);      // THIS

    cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);       // THIS
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, notdec);   // THIS
    java.util.Date date1 = cal1.getTime();

    cell1.setCellValue(formatter.format(date1));
}
```

**as you have not typed your desired output, I am guessing this is maybe what you want**